# How to get unique an array of objects back from a complex an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I get unique values from this input JSON array on field `input[i].user`

I can write a for loop but wanted to know if there is a shorter way using filter/set etc ? Thanks

```js
const input = [{
  "id": 133557,
  "user": "bcasey1",
  "userfullname": "Bertha Casey",
  "commentTypeId": 2,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 141614,
  "comment": "Red color on ravioli is not true, fix",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "133557-0",
  "timestamp": "Tue Apr 24 10:40:42 CDT 2018",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134038,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 1,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142286,
  "comment": "test123",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134038-0",
  "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22:15:18 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134039,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 2,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142287,
  "comment": "test234",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134039-0",
  "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22:15:35 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134112,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 3,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142361,
  "comment": "sadasdasd",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134112-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:03:55 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134112,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142370,
  "comment": "sadasdasd s",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134112-1",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 15:09:48 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134113,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 4,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142362,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #4",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134113-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:16:39 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134114,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142363,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #5",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134114-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:20:06 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134114,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142365,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #6",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134114-1",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:36:53 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134114,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142366,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #7",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134114-2",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:46:36 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134115,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 2,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142367,
  "comment": "eertet",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134115-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 14:50:03 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134118,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 3,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142371,
  "comment": "a",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134118-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 15:09:58 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}];

const expectedOutput = [{
  "user": "bcasey1",
  "userfullname": "Bertha Casey"
}, {
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
}];

console.log('expectedOutput', expectedOutput);
```

Comment: It's not a "JSON array"; it's an array of objects.

Comment: There is no attempt.  You are just showing an input and an output.  Please put in some work.

Comment: @Pointy edited thanks

Comment: The question is missing an important detail: what should happen when there are different "full name" entries for the same "user" value?

Comment: @Pointy please read carefully `this input JSON array on field input[i].user` apologies for my communication skills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative, you could `map` to the simplified "user", "userfullname" object then `filter` on where the index is the same as the result of `findIndex` where "user" is equal (a way to unique for javascript arrays)

```js
const input = [{
  "id": 133557,
  "user": "bcasey1",
  "userfullname": "Bertha Casey",
  "commentTypeId": 2,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 141614,
  "comment": "Red color on ravioli is not true, fix",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "133557-0",
  "timestamp": "Tue Apr 24 10:40:42 CDT 2018",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134038,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 1,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142286,
  "comment": "test123",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134038-0",
  "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22:15:18 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134039,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 2,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142287,
  "comment": "test234",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134039-0",
  "timestamp": "Mon Jul 8 22:15:35 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134112,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 3,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142361,
  "comment": "sadasdasd",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134112-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:03:55 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134112,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142370,
  "comment": "sadasdasd s",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134112-1",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 15:09:48 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134113,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 4,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142362,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #4",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134113-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:16:39 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134114,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142363,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #5",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134114-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:20:06 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134114,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142365,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #6",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134114-1",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:36:53 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134114,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 0,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142366,
  "comment": "sadasdasd edited #7",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134114-2",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 13:46:36 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134115,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 2,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142367,
  "comment": "eertet",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134115-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 14:50:03 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}, {
  "id": 134118,
  "user": "admin",
  "userfullname": "Administrator Administrator",
  "commentTypeId": 3,
  "annotationPrimaryId": 142371,
  "comment": "a",
  "deleted": false,
  "historyno": "134118-0",
  "timestamp": "Wed Jul 17 15:09:58 CDT 2019",
  "type": "rectangle"
}];

const simpleInput = input.map(({ user, userfullname }) => ({ user, userfullname }));

const filteredInput = simpleInput.filter((user, i, a) => i == a.findIndex(u => u.user == user.user));

console.log(filteredInput)
```

Comment: I am going to accept your answer as it is faster than @User863's answer https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/54sg1rtf/1/

Answer (score 4):

Using `reduce()` and `Object.assign()`

```js
const input = [{"id":133557,"user":"bcasey1","userfullname":"Bertha Casey","commentTypeId":2,"annotationPrimaryId":141614,"comment":"Red color on ravioli is not true, fix","deleted":false,"historyno":"133557-0","timestamp":"Tue Apr 24 10:40:42 CDT 2018","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134038,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":1,"annotationPrimaryId":142286,"comment":"test123","deleted":false,"historyno":"134038-0","timestamp":"Mon Jul 8 22:15:18 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134039,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":2,"annotationPrimaryId":142287,"comment":"test234","deleted":false,"historyno":"134039-0","timestamp":"Mon Jul 8 22:15:35 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134112,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":3,"annotationPrimaryId":142361,"comment":"sadasdasd","deleted":false,"historyno":"134112-0","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 13:03:55 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134112,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":0,"annotationPrimaryId":142370,"comment":"sadasdasd s","deleted":false,"historyno":"134112-1","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 15:09:48 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134113,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":4,"annotationPrimaryId":142362,"comment":"sadasdasd edited #4","deleted":false,"historyno":"134113-0","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 13:16:39 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134114,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":0,"annotationPrimaryId":142363,"comment":"sadasdasd edited #5","deleted":false,"historyno":"134114-0","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 13:20:06 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134114,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":0,"annotationPrimaryId":142365,"comment":"sadasdasd edited #6","deleted":false,"historyno":"134114-1","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 13:36:53 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134114,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":0,"annotationPrimaryId":142366,"comment":"sadasdasd edited #7","deleted":false,"historyno":"134114-2","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 13:46:36 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134115,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":2,"annotationPrimaryId":142367,"comment":"eertet","deleted":false,"historyno":"134115-0","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 14:50:03 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"},{"id":134118,"user":"admin","userfullname":"Administrator Administrator","commentTypeId":3,"annotationPrimaryId":142371,"comment":"a","deleted":false,"historyno":"134118-0","timestamp":"Wed Jul 17 15:09:58 CDT 2019","type":"rectangle"}];

const expectedOutput = input.reduce((a, o) => Object.assign(a, {
  [o.user]: {
    user: o.user,
    userfullname: o.userfullname
  }
}), {});

console.log('expectedOutput', Object.values(expectedOutput));
```

Comment: Why call `Object.assign()`? Why not just set `a[o.user]` to a value?

Comment: @Pointy that looks cleaner i think

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand well your question, but maybe this works for you:

```
let users_id = input.map( d => d.id );

// --> [133557,133558,...]
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont want just a list of userids

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `Object.keys()` and `.reduce()`:

```
const uniqueNames = Object.keys(input.reduce((names, obj) => (names[obj.user] = 1, names), {}));
```

The `.reduce()` operation creates an object whose property names are the "user" property values from the objects in the original array. The `Object.keys()` call then creates an array of those property names.

If you want the "full name" values, you can replace `1` by that and skip the `Object.keys()` call, or use `Object.entries()` to get an array of user and full names:

```
const usersAndNames = Object.entries(input.reduce((users, obj) => (obj[users] = obj.userfullname, obj), {}));
```

Comment: @dota2pro well look at the answers, see what they do, and then adapt the code to your precise requirements.

Comment: still not correct, please see the last element of the array https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/bhow1Lmy/4/