# Angular ngIf to only show unique value from array without using a pipe as it is not good practice

Tags: angular

in my foods.service.ts, I have an array

```
[{
  "category": "dogfood", "flavor": "chicken",
  "category": "catfood", "flavor": "beef",
  "category": "birdfood", "flavor": "sunflower",
  "category": "dogfood", "flavor": "beef",
  "category": "dogfood", "flavor": "chicken"

}]
```

then in my food.component.html I have my loop:

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor = "let food of foods">
    <span>{{food.category}}</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

if I run it as such I get duplicate values of dogfood. what I ideally want is to only return a list with unique value. for instance, it should return:

- dogfood
- catfood
- birdfood

as dogfood has already been displayed. I know I need to add a *ngIf to the span tag but not sure what to put there or even if this is the correct place to do so.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097662/how-to-get-unique-an-array-of-objects-back-from-a-complex-an-array-of-objects just filter the array before `*ngFor`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply filters to \*ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Comment: filter in your component and `*ngFor` over the updated array!

Comment: You can either create a pipe that you will use in *ngFor or filter the array in your component

Comment: @Dino I would recommend avoiding a filter pipe for these reasons: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe